# AB or BA but DRY

Tags: java

Bias in experiments is an important element to address. Imagine a robotic pipette system handling two different types of samples: A; and, B. The robot could repeat the same process, placing the same sample in the same position:

```
A B
A B
A B
A B
...
```

but doing so might introduce an environmental bias; to avoid that bias, the robot could randomly places sample A in left or right position:

```
B A
B A
A B
B A
A B
A B
...
```

Similarly, to avoid program structure bias, a common pattern is to randomly select the order of tasks, e.g., for tasks A and B, we could write:

```
if (0.5 < Math.random()) {
    doA(); doB();
} else {
    doB(); doA();
}
```

which is imperative, WET, and ugly; and, it does not scale. Are there better ways to avoid program structure bias based on task execution?

Comment: Downvoter -- I'm happy to clarify the question and/or help you understand but I need more than a -1 to do that. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a shuffled collection of tasks:

```
List<Task> tasks = createTaskList();
Collections.shuffle(tasks);
tasks.forEach(Task::do);
```

which is declarative, DRY, and it scales.

Comment: Why could you not abstract `Task.do()` from `doA()` and `doB()` without the `List` or `Shuffle`? Also, why not use a `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not sure what you're suggesting.

Comment: An executor could parallelize computation but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: In your question, where is `Task::do`?

Comment: The `Task` is the abstraction of `doA` and `doB` with a common `do`...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch OK, so `List<Runnable> runnables = Arrays.asList(this::doA, this::doB);`; but then what are you suggesting without the `List`, shuffle, and with an `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @Andy I'm trying to work out what the actual problem was that this solved. Or where this code can be practically applied. Hence the questions. I don't think I've made any recommendations yet. And I'm on my phone...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch -- I edited-in a bit of motivation to help you understand where this code is "practically applied".

Comment: Does a method named `do` compile? :)

Comment: :D Alex -- it do!